# Help with twitter echo & oauth in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter

My app requires from users to login with their twitter acount! I am using tardate oauth lib (from Paul Gallagher). That works fine.  I wanna create an API for my website (actually the user authentication part). Twitter Basic Auth has been deprecated and now twitter uses twitter echo. If a user wants to upload a file via api in my app, he must include in his request the above header.  So, my problem is: (i suppose that header hits twitter api directly and twitter returns in my url the response..is this right?)

how my app can handle the twitter response? json that contains user's info (or a negative response 401), in order to continue the uploading or not. Something like the twitpic API does.(http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/2/upload/) or by similar services.

```
curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Service-Provider: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json' -H 'X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com/",
oauth_consumer_key="yTrEIQH6jhtmLUypg8T5", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",  
oauth_token="514797-YuI8aYUDRmykzVKrgoLhXSq67TEa5ruc4GJC2rWTyu",oauth_timestamp="1271323750",
oauth_nonce="oYu6nMTQIZvqvlfXM56aBLAf5noGD0AQR3Fmi7U9Y", 
oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="CV4bTfE7Rs9J1kafTGwufLJdspo%3D"' -F "file=@/path/to/file" http://localhost:3000/api/upload.xml
```

my def upload currently works for a simple upload via api. Without a user info. But in this way my app doesn't know the file owner!

```
def upload
        file = File.new
        file.file = params[:file]
        # ... extra code
        respond_to do |format|
            if file.save                
                format.xml  { render :xml => file, :status => :created, :location => file }
            else
                format.xml  { render :xml => file.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }    
            end
        end
     end
```

Do you have any idea how can be the coding logic?

Any help will be highly appreciated :-)

Comment: The user has already accept your application from Twitter and it's his credential send by twitter. Isn't it ?

Comment: Mostly yes, with his tokens stored in database. But, also in case that user doesn't exist, app should try to authenticate him using those parameters! (header)

Comment: It's not clear to me if this request hits twitter api directly, or needs my app to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way is to grab headers and then use Patron..

```
auth_headers = request.headers["X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization"]
```

Patron can make a post request to `https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json` and then check the resp status!

Comment: Nevertheless, i had some problems with a post patron method..but this is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it would work in your specific case and I'm not sure if your considering using other plugins but the ones that I've used are OmniAuth and OmniSocial which is actually built off of omniauth.

You can find some great screencasts on omniauth here from Ryan Bates. Even if you don't plan on using omniauth, you might find some useful logic in his screencasts for your situation.

### Omniauth

[Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)

[Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2)

OR check out omnisocial here

### Omnisocial

[Intorudction to Omnisocial](http://icelab.com.au/articles/welcome-to-the-omnisocial/)

[Omnisocial on Github](https://github.com/icelab/omnisocial)

I hope this helps you! Good luck!