# Grab headers from curl request in Rails!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, curl

How rails can grab headers of a curl request like:

```
curl -v -H 'X-Auth-Service-Provider: https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json' -H 'X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com/",
oauth_consumer_key="yTrEIQH6jhtmLUypg8T5", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",  
oauth_token="514797-YuI8aYUDRmykzVKrgoLhXSq67TEa5ruc4GJC2rWTyu",oauth_timestamp="1271323750",
oauth_nonce="oYu6nMTQIZvqvlfXM56aBLAf5noGD0AQR3Fmi7U9Y", 
oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="CV4bTfE7Rs9J1kafTGwufLJdspo%3D"' -F "file=@/path/to/file" http://localhost:3000/api/upload.xml
```

Grab those values: `oauth_cosumer`, `oauth_token`, `oauth_timestamp` etc.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the whole request as a command string, as above?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with twitter echo & oauth in my rails app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074227/help-with-twitter-echo-oauth-in-my-rails-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
headers['oauth_consumer_key']
```

etc...